# Polygon with cylindrical edges

Tags: modeling

I am trying to model regular polygons (triangle, square, pentagon, hexagon, etc.) with the edges made up of cylindrical rods, kind of like the bonds in a molecule. I can get the basic shape by working with a circle mesh and changing to the appropriate number of vertices, but would appreciate some help in changing the edges to cylindrical "bonds." An example of a folded hexagon that I am trying to model is shown below. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure to understand what it should look like. Have you tried to add a skin modifier then a subdivision modifier ?

Comment: Sorry for not being very clear. Just added an image of a folded hexagon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to bevel a curve object.

Go to Blender Preferences > Add-ons. Type "extra" in the search bar, and activate the Add Curve: Extra Objects add-on by checking the box next to it.

[image]

Then in the 3D Viewport press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>, choose Curve > Polygon and set the sides to 6.

In the Properties window, go to Object Data Properties > Bevel, and change the Depth value to give the curve thickness.

[image]

Then move and rotate the vertexes in Edit Mode to get the desired result.

[image]

If you want the corners to be less sharp and more rounded you can change the handle type of the selected vertices (from the original Vector) to Aligned. You can also use Vector and Aligned vertices together in one curve to get a more precise result.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Alternatively (which I quite stupidly didn't realize before) you can place Spheres to represent the atoms at the corners of the curve. If you would use a Hook modifier the curve would follow the position of the atom object.

Select the curve. Go into Edit Mode. Select a corner Vertex. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and choose Cursor to Selected. Go to object mode and Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and choose a spherical object like Mesh > UV Sphere. (Press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale it down)

Now select the the sphere and <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the curve (in that order) so both are selected. Go into Edit model and select the curve vertex and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> and choose Hook to Selected object.

[image]

However if you choose to do this, you might want to parent the curve and all its atoms to an empty object, to be able to move the molecule (by moving the empty) without issues. (Add an empty, move it in the center of your molecule, select al the parts of the molecule, <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the empty, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and choose Object(keep Transform). )

Comment: Ooops, you just beat me to it!  I'll eave mine in, just for the differences.

Comment: I didn't even realise the object should have spheres, but since it is about a scientific model of a molecule it makes sense of course. Also I think instancing the spheres is the easiest way to go. So +1 : ) Though the Hook modifier would allow different atoms to move with the curve vertices (I might edit my answer accordingly.)

Comment: Hooking! Good idea :) All depends on what OP needs to do with these models .. maybe we've both gone OTT

Comment: Quite possibly, yes : )

Comment: This is "super" helpful. Especially because I can now do this with or without the spheres for atoms depending on the model I am trying to make. I'll need the corners to be sharp rather than rounded but thank you for letting me know how to do either one. What a great community!

Answer (score 4):

One route would be via Curves (make them 2D, if your polygons are planar.)

- Enable the shipped add-on 'Add Curve: Extra Objects' This will give you a polygonal curve option.
- Create your polygon of choice, and (for the optional next part,) <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> make  a copy of it, and *Header > Object menu > Convert* that to a mesh.
- In its geometry panel, ensure  the original (if 2D) curve-polygon has no fill, and give it a bevel, of whatever resolution and thickness suits.

For the second part, you could take some of the tedium out of placing atoms on your polygons by:

- In the Mesh copy, *Object Properties* tab > *Relations* panel > *Instancing*, set instancing to *Vertex*.
- Create a sphere at the origin (pivot) of the original Curve-polygon You can hide that one, eventually.
- Parent the sphere to the mesh copy. Duplicates should appear on the corners of the curve.
- You can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> the dupliverts, > Make Instances Real. Then you can scale them independently in Object mode.
- You can give them independent materials by associating the materials with the Objects, rather than their Data, just under the materials list panel in the  *Materials* tab.

[image]

Eventually, you could parent the atoms to their polygons / various polygons to one another so they move about together, or convert the whole lot to joined? meshes if you're going in that kind of direction.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the Skin Modifier and the Subdivision surface modifier.
[image]

If you need more precise control over it, you can select all the vertices, hit E to extrude and then S to scale it a little bigger, and then select everything again, hit E, and extrude upward.  You can then use the subdivision surface modifier to make the edges round, and select any edges you want to be sharp, press Shit+E and then drag the mouse out to create a sharp edge.

Comment: I don't know much about the skin modifier and never used it before. So this is a good chance to try it out. Looks like this is a useful one to know for some of my other projects as well. Thanks for suggesting this different approach.